# Ugly legacy date format java code cause an error in SonarQube 5.3

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am a very newbie to SonarQube. The following code ran correctly with SonarQube 5.2 (with rule violation "Printf-style format strings should not lead to unexpected behavior at runtime") but cause an error with SonarQube 5.3:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar
  (default-cli) on project art: SonarQube is unable to analyze file:
  'D:\workspace\art\src\main\java\grp\art\Iso8601Util.java': index (1)
  must be less than size (1) -> [Help 1]
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index (1) must be less than size (1)
  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:301)
  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:280)
  at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableList.get(RegularImmutableList.java:91)
  at org.sonar.java.checks.PrintfCheck.verifyParameters(PrintfCheck.java:173)
  at org.sonar.java.checks.PrintfCheck.onMethodInvocationFound(PrintfCheck.java:112)
  at org.sonar.java.checks.methods.AbstractMethodDetection.checkInvocation(AbstractMethodDetection.java:52)
  at org.sonar.java.checks.methods.AbstractMethodDetection.visitNode(AbstractMethodDetection.java:43)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:89)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:72)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:65)
  at org.sonar.java.checks.SubscriptionBaseVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionBaseVisitor.java:33)
  at org.sonar.java.model.InternalVisitorsBridge.visitFile(InternalVisitorsBridge.java:111)
  at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:97)
  ... 54 more
```

I just use the SonarQube Java Plugin out of the box, maven 3.2.1 through Eclipse/m2e and org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1 (`mvn sonar:sonar --errors -Dsonar.host.url=http://myserver:9000/`)

I am going to use SimpleDateFormat instead of String.format but I just report a maybe unexpected behaviour in SonarQube 5.3.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Iso8601Util {

  /**
   * @return Date formatté en 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
   */
   public static String now() {
      return format(new Date());
   }

   /**
    * @return Date formatté en 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
    */
    public static String format(Date date) {
       return String.format("%tFT%<tTZ", date);
    }

   /**
    * @return Date formatté en 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    */
    public static String formatWithoutTZ(Date date) {
      return String.format("%tF %<tT", date);
    }

   /**
    * @return Date formatté en 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z mais utilisable
    * pour un chemin de fichier (ou de répertoire) pour Windows.
    */
    public static String nowWindowsFileCompatible() {
      return now().replace(":", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SonarQube 5.3 I assume you are using the default bundled java plugin which is version 3.7.1.

Therefore you are hitting this issue https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1369 that has been solved in java plugin 3.8

So please upgrade to latest sonar-java plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When upgrading to the sonar-java-plugin 3.9, the error with SonarQube 5.3 disappeared and there is no more rule violation as with SonarQube 5.2.